# Maui Splash Screen no image displayed

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am using Visual Studio 2022 17.5.0 Preview 2.0 (also tried with Preview 1.0).

I am building to a physical device running Android 12 - API 31

I am creating a brand new Maui App project without any changes (tried both .NET 6 and .NET 7).

My problem is the Splash screen is not displaying the splash.svg image that contains the white .NET logo, theres just the purple background, nothing else. The issue started at some point after updating visual studio, is my best guess.

Anyone have a similar experience or solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to download a svg from the svg picture website.

And I found a similar issue in the MAUI Github page: [API 31 (Android 12) svg on splashscreen is not showing](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7289).

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Apparently microsoft insists that it is fixed from what I can see here https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/8394 and they then just close any new issues opened about it.

Comment: Marking this as solution since the solution seems to be that it is a Microsoft problem that Microsoft is not interested in fixing and/or might randomly fix in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Below steps worked for me,
Rename the splash file name (svg or png).
Set the build action to 'MauiSplashScreen'.
Clean the solution.
Rebuild solution.
Uninstall app.
Switch/Restart simulator/emulator/device.
Deploy