# Is there a known bug when changing splash screen in .Net Maui?

Tags: ios, screen, maui, splash-screen

Unfortunately I am really in despair. I am trying to change the splashscreen of my Maui App on my IPhone. In vain.

I have already searched all forums from Github

- https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10079
- https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8685
- ...

to StackOverview

- [Maui Splash Screen no image displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74992214/maui-splash-screen-no-image-displayed)
- [Cannot change .NET MAUI Blazor Splash screen on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334806/cannot-change-net-maui-blazor-splash-screen-on-ios)
- ...

to various blogs explaining how to change it, but none of the proposed solutions worked.

I have already created new projects several times and not once did changing the splash screen work.

Specifically, my `.csproj` file looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>MauiApp3</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>MauiApp3</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.mauiapp3</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>752fae99-4b98-435c-83b0-a3648a397ff3</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net7.0-ios'">
      <CodesignKey>Apple Development: Created via API (748AD89WJ9)</CodesignKey>
      <CodesignProvision>VS: WildCard Development</CodesignProvision>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="7.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Furthermore splash.svg must have the BuildAction MauiSplashScreen. It does, see picture 1.

[image: Navigator and properties of splash.svg]

My files in the 'Platforms' folder (AppDelegate, Info.plist,...) are unchanged.
Clean, Rebuild, ... nothing helps.
The logs in the output for starting the app look like this:

```
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/Microsoft.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Collections.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Threading.Thread.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Threading.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.Http.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.Sockets.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Drawing.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Private.Uri.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Application.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/netstandard.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.IO.Pipes.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Memory.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.NameResolution.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.ComponentModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.ObjectModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Collections.Immutable.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Linq.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.IO.Compression.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Collections.Specialized.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Security.Cryptography.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Formats.Asn1.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Runtime.Loader.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Security.Claims.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Resources.Writer.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Xml.XDocument.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Private.Xml.Linq.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Private.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.Quic.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.IO.Compression.Brotli.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Threading.Channels.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Reflection.Emit.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Linq.Expressions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Console.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Data.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Transactions.Local.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Linq.Queryable.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Linq.Parallel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.Requests.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.ServicePoint.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.HttpListener.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.WebSockets.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.WebClient.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.WebProxy.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.Mail.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.Ping.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Threading.Overlapped.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Web.HttpUtility.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Xml.XPath.dll [External]
Thread started:  #2
Thread started: .NET Timer #3
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/MauiApp3.dll
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.Maui.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll [External]
2023-09-06 19:26:07.969 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[10643:757635] AppDelegate name: AppDelegate

2023-09-06 19:26:07.931 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[10643:757635] Content folder: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content

2023-09-06 19:26:07.933 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[10643:757635] App path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/MauiApp3.dll

Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'MauiApp3.Program.Main(System.String[])' to C:\Users\Stefan\Development\MauiApp3\MauiApp3\Platforms\iOS\Program.cs:10 [0x00000].
Loaded assembly: data-0x11096c000 [External]
Loaded assembly: data-0x110980000 [External]
Loaded assembly: data-0x110994000 [External]
Loaded assembly: data-0x1109e8000 [External]
Loaded assembly: data-0x1109fc000 [External]
Thread started:  #4
Thread started: .NET ThreadPool Gate #5
Thread started:  #6
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointSendToIde(System.String)' to D:\a\_work\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:423 [0x00000].
Thread started:  #7
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Text.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointCheckpoint()' to D:\a\_work\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:418 [0x00000].
2023-09-06 19:26:08.232 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[10643:757635] Could not resolve assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll' or one of its dependencies.

2023-09-06 19:26:08.228 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[10643:757635] Could not resolve assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll' or one of its dependencies.

2023-09-06 19:26:08.311 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[10643:757635] Could not resolve assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll' or one of its dependencies.

2023-09-06 19:26:08.313 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[10643:757635] Could not resolve assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll' or one of its dependencies.

Thread started:  #8
Thread started:  #9
Thread started:  #10
2023-09-06 19:26:08.803 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[10643:757635] Could not resolve assembly System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=en-DE, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.

2023-09-06 19:26:08.804 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[10643:757635] Could not resolve assembly System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A97B4008-8011-47DE-97E0-B73468324369/Documents/MauiApp3.content/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.

Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DBB2C6E6-01D4-4BD7-B220-765D82D8A3CC/MauiApp3.app/System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll [External]
Thread started:  #11
Thread finished:  #4
The thread 0x4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Please help me. :( I am about to finish my app, but unfortunately it fails only the splashscreen. Is there a known bug in that area?

(Further information: Everything is up to date [Device, VS, .Net Maui])

I changed the MauiSplashScreen Property and expected to see my default image.(Actual it is svg file! Just to show you the image it is png)
[image: My default splashscreen, what I expect to see]

1. Renamed the original splash to splash_old.
2. Added my new splash.svg
3. Added in .csproj file:
   `<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />`
4. Clean and always delete previous apps on my IPhone
5. Rebuild
6. Deploy and Run on my IPhone
7. Rerunning the app without VS22

My result: No changes and still the default .Net Icon on purple background.

Comment: It should be an issue. You can [report it to GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

Answer (score 0):

It's weird. I followed your steps, and failed as you said. Then I referred to the official doc: [Splash screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android), but still failed.

But I fixed it by th following steps:

1. put the image you want to use it as splashscreen into `Images` folder.
2. set the image's Build Action to `MauiImage`
3. Add `<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Images\pxlkb.png" Color="#ffffff" BaseSize="64,64" />` in .csproj file

Here is the

[image: effect].

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately your workaround did not work.
I have now of necessity created an Android emulator and there the splash screen (and icon) can be changed. With the official way and your workaround.
Unfortunately I do not understand why it does not work on my IPhone 11.

Comment: I test the app on IPhone11(iOS:16.0/15.4/13.7) (simulator), and it all works well... Does it run on your real machine?

Comment: Everything expect the splash screen (and app icon) does work on my device.

Comment: @Stefano did you found any solution. I have same problem. Adroid work perfect but iOS not working